# Can I use 5V 6A SMPS to power up raspberry pi 3?

Tags: pi-3

Is it safe to use the output from SMPS to drive the Pi by cutting a USB cable and connecting the power wires to the raspberry pi by type B connector? If I want to use the same SMPS with the same voltage and current, what is the care taken to be made to save pi?

Answer (score 2):

In general: Yes - it is safe to use any power supply that meets the [USB standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Power), and delivers 5 volts to the RPi's DC power input.

Please note that I have qualified my answer with the phrase "meets USB standards", but this is not intended to exclude power supplies that are not tested and certified for compliance with the USB standards. Rather, it is meant to suggest that you should exercise some due diligence in your selection, and not select a supply willy-nilly without considering its specifications.

There are many power supply specifications; far too many to list here. But obviously the one of primary importance is its voltage output: ***5 volts DC***. Secondarily, the supply must be able to deliver ***at least*** enough current to meet the [USB power specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Power). Note that these are ***minimum*** requirements; your RPi will not (normally) draw any more current than that prescribed by the USB standards.

There are other considerations:

- This SE site is littered with hundreds of questions/issues due to substandard or misused input power. Try to ensure you get this right.
- Some extra care is called for using a power supply able to deliver very large currents. Consider an inline DC fuse to protect your supply and the downstream equipment.
- Some SMPS do not regulate well at very low currents. This can be an issue depending on the characteristics of the individual supply. Check for a "minimum current" specification on your supply.
- Cabling is often overlooked as a source of problems. Fine gauge wiring, or long cables/wiring can add enough of a voltage drop to create issues. Ensure you use a cable or wiring capable of delivering the current from the SMPS output terminal to the RPi input.